Importing Nat unknown
I am starting to learn Lean, using Mathematics in Lean, in particular using VS Code that I installed according to the documentation. I was hoping to use it to prove for instance that 2+2=4 or so (from the Natural Number game), typing
nth_rewrite 2 [two_eq_succ_one] -- only change the second `2` to `succ 1`.
rw [add_succ]
rw [one_eq_succ_zero]
rw [add_succ, add_zero] -- two rewrites at once
rw [← three_eq_succ_two] -- change `succ 2` to `3`
rw [← four_eq_succ_three]
rfl

Of course the functions there are unknown, I therefore imported the following packages
import data.nat.basic

But then I get the error "unknown module prefix 'data'" (same with Mathlib.Data.Nat.Dist). Shouldn't these packages be natively embedded in Mathlib and installed with the Lean extension in VS Code?
Thanks in advance!

Case matters: Data.Nat.Basic. Is there a particular reason that you want to prove 2 + 2 = 4 in such a roundabout way?

@AndrejBauer Thanks, but I also get a "Unknown package Data", maybe there is something wrong with my install? I am trying to prove it this way since it is one of the first exercises in the "Mathematics in Lean" book I try to follow

Here are the details. I include at the end the idomatic proof of 2 + 2 = 4. Note that Mathematics in Lean has an accompanying repository, and the Getting started section has instructions on how to set it up. I think you're meant to follow the Lean files provided there, you don't have to invent your own.
import Mathlib.Tactic.NthRewrite

/- The following four lemmas are not part of the standard
   library, they appear in the number game. -/
theorem one_eq_succ_zero: 1 = .succ 0 := by rfl
theorem two_eq_succ_one: 2 = .succ 1 := by rfl
theorem three_eq_succ_two: 3 = .succ 2 := by rfl
theorem four_eq_succ_three: 4 = .succ 3 := by rfl

theorem cow : 2 + 2 = 4 := by
  nth_rewrite 2 [two_eq_succ_one]
  rewrite [Nat.add_succ]
  rewrite [one_eq_succ_zero]
  rewrite [Nat.add_succ, Nat.add_zero] -- two rewrites at once
  rewrite [← three_eq_succ_two] -- change `succ 2` to `3`
  rewrite [← four_eq_succ_three]
  rfl

/-- A better way -/
example: 2 + 2 = 4 := by rfl

